# how to check on server if javascript is disabled?

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, css, .net-3.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if JavaScript is enabled with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454551/check-if-javascript-is-enabled-with-php)

Is there some way to check on server if a visitor have disabled its javascript in browser ?

I know about client side ways I want to check it server, kindly guide.

Comment: do something with javascript which reports "javascript enabled" to the server?

Comment: You shouldn't need to care if JS is on or off. Just build it right: http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to do something like show a message if they don't have JavaScript, then show the message by default and remove it with JavaScript.

There might be a way of doing this by setting a session variable and then making an AJAX call - if you don't receive the AJAX call then you can *guess* that they don't have JavaScript but you won't know. They might just have a slow connection.

Finally, the other way is to do something like Google Maps and redirect the user to a page with a nojs=true variable in the URL. You disable the redirect with JavaScript, so it only happens if the user doesn't have JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You will have to somehow send a value back from the client to the server and deal with it appropriately.

One thing I thought of was on the login form, insert a hidden form field that says something like "JavaScriptEnabled". So when the user logins, you can set the session to know this information.