# Detecting if JS enabled in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, user-agent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if JavaScript is enabled with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454551/check-if-javascript-is-enabled-with-php)

I need a way to detect if javascript is enabled or disabled in the user-agent in the codeigniter framework

Comment: No duplicate occurred, my question for codeignniter framework where `get_browser` function not work.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot detect this directly on the server-side. Please take a look at this article for alternative solutions: http://www.untwistedvortex.com/detect-javascript-enabled-php/

Comment: can i use `get_broswer` function ?

Comment: Here is a copy from the php.net website regarding the `get_browser` function: `get_browser — Tells what the user's browser is capable of`. It lets you know if JavaScript is supported on the user's browser, it can't tell you if it's enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get this information with the HTTP-headers. But i have a little workaround:

You can store this information in the User-Session. By default you suggest, that JS is disabled. The first delivered Page should execute a Ajax-Call to a script which tells the USER-Session, that Javascript is enabled.

Of course this has some disadvantages:

- The first Page-Call is allways no-script
- You don't get the information, if the User suddenly disables Javascript
- Searching-Engines could rate your page down, if you make big differences between the script- and the noscript version

Some times it is enough to have the information, if JS is enabled or not, in the CSS. 
You can do it like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Jquery version
        $(function() {
            $('body').removeClass('noJs');
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .noJs #hello {
             display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="noJs">
    <div id="hello">Hello</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do a reliable detection in CodeIgniter or other framework/plain PHP.

Besides, that information is not part of the standard browser header/user-agent.