# How to check javascript is enable/disable in Joomla2.5.14

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, joomla2.5

I am using Joomla latest version `2.5.14` and I want to apply some condition so I want to check is JavaScript is enable/disable.

Note: I want to check with server side side.

What I want:

```
if($sub_menu == "find" and $user->guest){
        if(){
            // if javascript is enable
        }else{
            // if javascript is disable 
        }               
    }else{
        echo $opentag . '<a class="maximenuck ' . $item->anchor_css . '" href="' . $item->flink . '"' . $title . $item->rel . '>' . $linktype . '</a>' . $closetag; 
    }
```

Comment: @Juhana hey i updated question i don't want to use <noscript></noscript>.

Comment: The "you can't do that" answer applies whether or not you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `if` and `else` and put all your javascript with tag `<noscript>`

```
<script>
document.write("Hello World!")
</script>
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Server-side you are not able to do that. Other thing is it does not matter you are using Joomla. You can use the conventional method. Try below

[How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)

[Check if JavaScript is enabled with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454551/check-if-javascript-is-enabled-with-php)