# Redirecting a One Page Website when javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am developing a one page website using html, css, javascript and php. I am using jQuery to handle all the navigation of the website, so when a user clicks a link in the navigation menu then the current content will fade out and the content the user chose to view will fade in.

For sake of progressive enhancement and taking into consideration users without javascript I am going to split the content out into seperate pages that I want to be displayed to the user if javascript is disabled, thus allowing users without javascript enabled to still navigate around the site  without a problem.

I am relatively new to php so I am having a slight  problem figuring out how to do this. Is there a php function that will return whether or not the user has javascript enabled ?

So the  code would be something like:

```
<?php

  if (!javascript) {

    header('Location: home.php');
  }

?>
```

where home.php would be the page catered to users  without javascript. Or am I looking at this problem in the wrong way ?

Comment: You can't check if javascript is enabled with PHP: [Check if JavaScript is enabled with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4454557/3361444)

Comment: May be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled
will help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the HTML `<noscript>` tag.

e.g.:

```
<html>
<head>
<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com/"/></noscript>
...
```

Comment: So this  would redirect my page if scripts are not allowed ??

Comment: @Mikey sure this is specially for that you want

Comment: @Mikey Exactly. The `<noscript>` tag's contents are ignored by Javascript-enabled sessions.

Comment: Thanks  !   Works exactly like I  need

Answer (score 3):

## Use [noscript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FElement%2Fnoscript)

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=home.html" />
</noscript>
```