# How to check if Javascript is enabled or not in browser using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I need to check from server side if client machine is Javascript enabled or not.
Is it possible in PHP? If it is, how?

Comment: Ajax call to the server on page load. If the call happens, javascript is enabled.

Comment: It's possible using AJAX as arao wrote, I have another question. Why you need to know that on server? I mean you what to solve something what should be solved better without this knowledge.

Comment: You can use this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9503382/473016)

Comment: Why in earth do you want to do this with PHP ? Use javascript itself, or even `HTML` `noscript` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `ajax` from client, if it works then javascript is enabled

With jQuery you can simply:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/checkjavascript.php"
});
```

if your php receives call from client then Javascript is enabled in the client