# How to capture a javascript disabled client using php

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a mobile mail app where I have created 2 versions of the app, the one is for javascript disabled devices. I want to redirect my users (if they visit the app using a javascript disabled device) to the non-js version of my site.

How can I know if the device is javascript disabled from server side?

I tested the following code on a javascript disabled device, instead of printing "Javascript is not enabled", It is returning empty .

```
$x="<script> document.write('hello world');</script>";

if(empty($x)) {
   echo "Javascript not enabled";
}
```

Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: You can't do it via PHP - [read more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4454557/2518525) (*well you can, with cumbersome, overkill code, but that's not what you want.*)

Comment: There is a messy way of doing this.  Have your browser check in with the app via an ajax call.  If the users session receives no check in within X time then redirect to the non-js app on the next page load - you don't have JS to redirect so you have to wait for the user to take action.  This isn't graceful and rather than doing something like this - you should plan for the absence of javascript if that is a major concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

noscript blocks are executed when JavaScript is disabled.

Example :

```
<script> 
document.write('hello world');
</script>

<noscript>
    <a href="pagewithoutjs.php?">Some Page</a>
</noscript>
```

Users without js will get the pagewithoutjs.php