# Setting SESSION variables using JavaScript AJAX (i.e., not using JQuery AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

My goal is to set a session variable using an AJAX call that is written in plain JavaScript, not using JQuery. There are two files: The `index.php` file, and the PHP file called by the AJAX, `ajax_set_session.php`.

`index.php` starts a new session, sets the SESSION variable `MyVariable` to the string 'false' (i.e. not to the boolean `false`), prints the contents of SESSION, and then writes out the AJAX routine, which calls `ajax_set_session.php`. In turn, that resets `MyVariable` to 'true' and creates a new SESSION variable, `YourVariable`, to which is assigned the string 'xxx'. The contents of the revised SESSION are printed to the console within `ajax_set_session.php`, and when the code is executed, the one variable is, in fact, revised and the other is created. The `index.php` file then resumes and prints out the contents of SESSION, which are *not* revised, which I do not understand. I've checked the `session_id` between the two files, and it is the same.

Here is the code for `index.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
session_unset();
print_r('<pre>');
print_r('Before script:' . PHP_EOL);
$_SESSION['MyVariable'] = 'false';
print_r($_SESSION);
print_r('</pre>');
?>
<script>
var ajax = {};
var hasAX = window.hasOwnProperty("ActiveXObject");
ajax.x = function () {
    if (hasAX) {
        var versions = ["MSXML2.XmlHttp.6.0", "MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0", "MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0", "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0", "MSXML2.XmlHttp.2.0", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"];
        var xhr;
        var i = 0;
        while (i < versions.length) {
            try {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);
                break;
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
            i += 1;
        }
        return xhr;
    } else {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
};

ajax.send = function (url, callback, method, data, async) {
    if (async === undefined) {
        async = true;
    }
    var x = ajax.x();
    x.open(method, url, async);
    x.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (x.readyState === 4) {
            callback(x.responseText);
        }
    };
    if (method === 'POST') {
        x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    }
    x.send(data);
};

ajax.post = function (url, data, callback, async) {
    var query = [];
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
        query.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]));
    });
    ajax.send(url, callback, 'POST', query.join('&'), async);
};

function logStuff(userData) {
    if (typeof userData === "string") {
        console.log(userData);
    } else if (typeof userData === "object") {
        Object.keys(userData).forEach(function (key) {
            console.log(key + ": " + userData[key]);
        });
    }
}

ajax.post('ajax_set_session.php', {MyVariable: 'true', YourVariable: 'xxx'}, logStuff, true);

</script>
<?php
print_r('<pre>');
print_r('After script:' . PHP_EOL);
print_r($_SESSION);
print_r('</pre>');
?>
```

And here is the code for `ajax_set_session.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}
print_r($_SESSION);
exit();
?>
```

If you run the code with the developer's console open, you'll see that SESSION is unchanged in the `index.php` file but it changes as expected in the `ajax_set_session.php` file. Why are the changes to SESSION not being retained? (I've tried switching between `async` true and false in the `index.php` AJAX routine, but to no avail.)

Comment: How exactly did you check the session id “between the two files”? Have you checked in network panel, if your AJAX request sends the session cookie?

Comment: You don't understand script workflow. PHP script doesn't `resume`. It runs completely on server side and gives you html/js-codes and dies. After that your ajax code starts and sets a session variable. That's why you don't see any changes in `$_SESSION` output.

Comment: @CBroe echoing session_id() at the top of each script confirms the same session is use in each script

Comment: @u_mulder Not true; with PHP, I can write to the client an HTML form and a <script> that immediately processes it (the form), which stops the flow of the PHP that has written it. What's unclear is why that should work but this should not.

Comment: No, you __can't__.

Comment: Pretty sure @u_mulder is right, you seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how these things actually work. You should go read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming and make sure you understand what what’s explained there means.

Comment: @CBroe See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454551/check-if-javascript-is-enabled-with-php/4454557 , 6th response down in the "oldest" response tab, the response by Gianluca Lodigiani. It works. I use it. So the question remains: How is it that Lodigiani's routine would work but my code above would not. (His response came from http://www.inspirationbit.com/php-js-detection-of-javascript-browser-settings/ , BTW, where the same technique is described.)

Comment: @u_mulder See my response to CBroe above for links demonstrating how this can and does work.

Comment: You still don't understand the server side and  client side programming. Your provided code from other question works because form is __submitted__ and __redirected__ to the same page. See the words - __SUBMITTED__, __REDIRECTED__? In your case with ajax there's __NO__ form submit and __NO__ redirection to anywhere. Therefore there no changes in `$_SESSION` data. Please, read @CBroe link again.